# Missing Index Recommendation - Partitioned Table

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have a strange situation whereby I have a query that is executed 1000s of times a day.
There is a missing index recommendation with an estimated impact of 99%.

The strange part is that this index already exists. And this index is already being seeked upon by the query

Points to note:

- Table is partitioned
- Index that already exists is partitioned aligned

What I noticed in the seek operator is that all partitions are being seeked.

[image]

There are 423 partitions.

Is SQL trying to tell me that I need a non-aligned index of the same definition?

The index recommendation create script that it gives me does **not** specify **ON PRIMARY** which means that it's going to be created as aligned.

The query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(1), MAX(Date_Column)
FROM Table_1 
WHERE Col1  = something AND Id > 0
```

The plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1UJK7VdT

Comment: This link seems to indicate that the missing index DMV doesn't understand partitioning correctly, so I would ignore it.  https://sqltouch.blogspot.com/2013/04/missing-index-dmvs-misleading-path.html

Comment: Every partition of the index will need to be touched when the query doesn't specify the partitioning column in WHERE/JOIN predicates. A non-partitioned index may be more efficient since it will result in 1 seek rather than 423 index seeks. Add the complete DDL to your question.

Comment: Furthermore to Dan's point, why are you using Partitioning?...what are you hoping to gain from it? FWIW, the missing index recommendations should almost always be ignored.